# Failed media upload: "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded."

Tags: php, uploads, media

I am running Linux CentOS 5.8 and I have my web pages using WordPress 4.0.

I am trying to uplad jpg photos to server via WordPress, but it randomly fails. I uploaded few photos, and then I get errors like:

```
“4.JPG” has failed to upload due to an error
The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.
```

Then I try again and again and again until it is successfuly uploaded. Very frustrating.

How can I debug this? Is there a log file? Where to look for?

Comment: Can you add more info on what webserver this is running on? Does this only happen with big files?

Comment: Files are only 100 kB. Webserver is Apache.

Comment: Same problem here. Apache/Debian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this problem with changing Apache server configuration: there is a KeepAlive flag which needs to be turned Off.

More about this flag:

[Apache Optimization: KeepAlive On or Off?](https://abdussamad.com/archives/169-Apache-optimization:-KeepAlive-On-or-Off.html)

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding

```
<?php header ("Connection: close"); ?>
```

in file.php situated under wp-admin/include

Comment: Never ever edit core files and BTW how does it solve the issue.

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly !

Comment: Yes worked, but how?

Answer (score 1):

Look at replay by Roberto:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33375823/error-dispatching-request-to-apache

```
RequestReadTimeout handshake=0 header=20-600,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500
```

By default Apache will stop upload after 20-30 seconds. With this directive placed into Apache config upload will continue up to 600 seconds as long as user is sending at least 500 bytes/s.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and tried doing a google search and came up with so many technical suggestions that I could not begin to even start as I'm not tech savvy. I did run into an article where a blogger said she contacted her hosting server and they changed the PHP version. It may or may not work for me but I was going to try.

Only I didn't know how to do that and I just got off with customer support and basically what he did was increase my bandwidth. I still couldn't upload. I did tell him in the add media library page it did say max upload file size was 2MB. But it wasn't until I refresh the page that the change kicked in and I saw my maximum upload file size was 256 MB. After that I was able to upload photos just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this, by removing libapache2-mod-php5filter:

```
apt-get remove libapache2-mod-php5filter
```

and installing libapache2-mod-php5:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5
```